# Can anyone told me how to prevent to store blank input field of multiple input in Django Models

Tags: django

In my form there are multiple input field means there are two fieldset in which same input fields are available and i want to store both that input into models in different ids. It is working but when i filled only one input field and click on submit button then the second one is also stored blank but i want to prevent it. It's means that i only want to store filled input field into model and blank one will not not stored.

### My Form.html

```
 <form class="well form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'fixed_doclist' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                      <fieldset>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Document Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="dname" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Exp Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="exp" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Renewal Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="renewdt" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Purpose</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="purpose" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Remarks</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="remark" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                       </fieldset><br/><br/>



                      <fieldset>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Document Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="fullName" name="dname1" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Exp Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="exp1" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Renewal Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="renewdt1" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Purpose</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="purpose1" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Remarks</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                               <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="remark1" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" value="" type="text"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                       </fieldset>

                         <button>Submit</button>
               </form>
```

### View.py File

```
def fixed_doclist(request):
    print("Form is submitted successfully!")
    dname = request.POST.get("dname", False)
    exp = request.POST.get("exp", False)
    renewdt = request.POST.get("renewdt", False)
    purpose = request.POST.get("purpose", False)
    remark = request.POST.get("remark", False)

    dname1 = request.POST.get("dname1", False)
    exp1 = request.POST.get("exp1", False)
    renewdt1 = request.POST.get("renewdt1", False)
    purpose1 = request.POST.get("purpose1", False)
    remark1 = request.POST.get("remark1", False)

    DocFixed = Doc.objects.bulk_create([Doc(dname = dname, exp = exp, renewdt = renewdt, purpose = purpose, remark = remark),Doc(dname = dname1, exp = exp1, renewdt = renewdt1, purpose = purpose1, remark = remark1)])

    return render(request,'fixeddoclist.html')
```

### Model.Py File

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    dname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    exp = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    renewdt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dname
```

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to create a `Doc` instance if _all_ fields for that Document are provided?

Comment: yes Sir @Will Keeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to create a `Doc` instance if all fields are provided, it should just be a case of checking that something is set for all fields. Since you might not have data for both `Doc` instances, you wouldn't need to bulk create.

For example:

```
def fixed_doclist(request):
    print("Form is submitted successfully!")

    doc_args = {
        dname: request.POST.get("dname", False), 
        exp: request.POST.get("exp", False), 
        renewdt: request.POST.get("renewdt", False), 
        purpose: request.POST.get("purpose", False), 
        remark: request.POST.get("remark", False)
    }

    doc1_args = {
        dname: request.POST.get("dname1", False), 
        exp: request.POST.get("exp1", False), 
        renewdt: request.POST.get("renewdt1", False), 
        purpose: request.POST.get("purpose1", False), 
        remark: request.POST.get("remark1", False)
    }

    if all(doc_args.values()):
        Doc.objects.create(**doc_args)

    if all(doc1_args.values()):
        Doc.objects.create(**doc1_args)

    return render(request,'fixeddoclist.html')
```

Comment: Thank You @Will Keeling. I'll update you once I'll check.

Comment: It's shows a error like name 'dname' is not defined in doc_args.

Comment: Error is solved. Now It's working fine according to my rquirements.